# Editing Theme to apply Co-Authors Plus

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to implement the [Co-Authors Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/co-authors-plus/) Plugin. It says that you will need to change some PHP in the theme. It outlines the changes on this [Link](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/).

I believe I have found where I would need to change it in my theme. In a file called "post-author-info.php".

This is what it looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Post Author Info
 *
 * @package WP Journal
 * @subpackage Include
 */
 ?>

<div id="authorinfo" class="columns alpha omega marT30 marB20">
    <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), '80' ); ?></a>
    <h5 class="marB10"><?php _e('By', 'contempo'); ?>: <a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></h5>
    <p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Just adding this line `<?php if ( function_exists( 'coauthors' ) ) { coauthors(); } else { the_author(); } ?>` seems to give me something that I want. Both "Admin" And "Andrew Gable" are displayed.

Here is the screen shot when changes are applied. [image: Photo]

I'm unsure on how to get it to link correctly, and how to handle photos and multiple Bio's.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna post this question at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

I had a similar issue and resolved it this way:

```
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;
foreach( get_coauthors() as $coauthor ): ?>
  <div class="entry-author co-author">
    <?php echo get_avatar( $coauthor->user_email, '96' ); ?>
    <h3 class="author vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $coauthor->ID, $coauthor->user_nicename ); ?>"><?php echo $coauthor->display_name; ?></a></span></h3>
    <p class="author-bio"><?php echo $coauthor->description; ?></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!-- .entry-author co-author -->
<?php endforeach;
```

Be sure to use that `global $post;`and the `foreach`-loop.

This function will display an author box containing author image/avatar, author name with link to its archive, and the author's bio. You might want to use your own theme's CSS classes though.